# Кликабельная картинка в маркере на панораме яндекс

Tags: яндекс-карты, панорамы

Возможно ли сделать [этот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/panorama_with_markers) так, что бы картинка (или текст) были кликабельными ссылками?

Answer (score 1):

Кликабельных ссылок нет, потому что маркеры рисуются исключительно картинками. Клика нет, но вместо него можно подписаться на `expand`/`collapse` и

```
player.events.add(['markerexpand', 'markercollapse'], (e) => {
    console.log('clicked', e.get('marker'));
})
```